# How to set belongs_to field to nil in ActiveRecord database(RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null, rails-activerecord

I have a database which contains comments. In the model file I state that a comment

```
belongs_to :user
```

And in the database there is a user_id field associated with the user it belongs to. Now when a comment is deleted, rather than actually destroying the entry I want to remove the comment's values and leave it as "This message has been deleted". However, it seems I am unable to set the user_id field to nil through rails. I've tried

```
@comment.user_id = nil
@comment.save
```

As well as

```
@comment.user = nil
@comment.save
```

But neither work. What is the solution?

Comment: Try setting `@comment.user_id` to `nil`. But your code should work as well (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Do you have any validations on the user_id field?

Comment: @eugen I don't think so, but where would such validations be? (Sorry I'm a bit of a noob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using a gem in creating a comment, there will be validations on the gem code.  You can always bypass these validations by updating via sql.  Either you bypass validations `@comment.save(validate: false)` or update using sql `@comment.update_column :user_id, nil`.

Comment: Thanks, both methods worked! Is one method preferable to the other for any reason?

Comment: the first one that calls save still runs the callbacks.  The other one doesn't so it depends on your needs :)